# Mongodb: Not able to add new key in nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema in mongodb like

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  agentCode: String,
  data: {
    type: Object,
    profDtl: {
      education: String      
    }
});
```

Now i want to add a new property `desgnName` in `profDtl`

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  agentCode: String,
  data: {
    type: Object,
    profDtl: {
      desgnName: String, // trying to add new property
      education: String      
    }
});
```

but it is not reflected in database

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for it, whenever add new property in mongodb schema, it required a default value to reflect on new entry

for Eg:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  agentCode: String,
  data: {
    type: Object,
    profDtl: {
      desgnName: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
      },
      education: String      
    }
});
```

now its working fine